# Are Steel SIPs Structural?

Tags: insulation, structural

I am from the Caribbean and we have a lot of termites so OSB SIPs are not an option, my question is this, are steel SIPs Structural like OSB SIPs?

SIP = Structural Insulated panels.

EPS = Expanded Polystyrene

OSB = Oriented strand board

thanks!

Comment: The structural insulated panels I have used have all been wood but, I live in Oregon. Lots of mills here. I would guess that there willing be similar types in steel but remember not all panels are insulated and the best are closed cell foam core in my opinion.  I don’t know if you are aware but carpenter ants and termites love the foam I don’t know if it is all types but both make nests and chew it up even there is no good value in the foam so check into that before thinking that because it’s steel the termites won’t affect the strength. With the wood panels the foam increases the rigidity.

Comment: I was thinking of getting PU Steel SIPs, not EPS.

Comment: I am not sure of the difference in polyurethane if it has the same issues just a heads up as that is the only problem I know of.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question, although it would be clearer if you explained the various acronyms. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Let me do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are steel SIPs Structural like OSB SIPs

Yes. They are generally equivalent as they both do the same job, for the same reason other than they are using different materials, wood based materials vs metal based materials. You can temporarily remove the specific materials from your thinking and everything is about the same, including where support members are located, where and how things are attached, etc. This is all about materials. During the design of the materials, the steel SIPs are designed such that they generally mimic the wood based materials. In reality, the actual numbers are likely different but this is on a smaller scale / fine tuning level

Comment: Got a concern, have you used PU panels before, personally?

Comment: No I have not personally and physically used any SIP panels, my carpentry and contractors days were before them. I am now a structural engineer