# Which is more preferred, PU SIP core panels or EPS SIP core panels?

Tags: insulation, structural

I am looking at something that can last a long time, has good structural component and provide good insulation. Which would be the preferred option in this case? I am from the Caribbean.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not edit & improve the original question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/189377/97780

Comment: I believe that he is doing exactly as our site suggests and posting a clear singular question. This is a different question than the original. So if anything, he is doing better than most by following the guidelines. My 2 cents

Comment: This may be more opinion based , possibly influenced by location as I mentioned in a comment to the original post.  termites and carpenter ants do tend to like polystyrene not positive about polyurethane. The issue is they nest in it Probably because it is soft and easy to tunnel through.